# Sanitize Razor syntax in a template to be used as the Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, content-management-system, code-injection

Here is the scenario. Currently we are storing Razor templates on disk for a multi-tenant CMS system. We need the ability for admins in a multi-tenant system to **upload their own website templates** (*layouts*), but in doing so we need to be sure that they won't contain any Razor markup which could potentially be harmful.

Effectively we want to be able to *encode* any Razor syntax that could have been included in the client's template.

**The proposal:**
Allow admins to upload a template that is decorated with *approved tags* using a safe template system, like [dotliquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/).
On upload, first replace all "@" signs with "@@" in order to escape **any potential Razor syntax**. Next, replace the *approved tags* with the appropriate Razor markup and save the template in a database.
Loading the page will utilize a custom *VirtualPathProvider* - out of scope for this question...

**Questions**

1. If I simply replace all "@" signs with "@@", will that effectively "encode" all razor markup that could have existed in the template?
2. Are there any concerns if the template contained legitimate "@" signs, like in an email address or twitter handle? My initial tests show that the double escape works.

## UPDATE

My tests show that escaping all "@" signs with another "@" sign will sanitize the template by escaping any Razor syntax. But I'd love to hear from someone that may have more in depth knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

1) Writing a function to inject razor code with @ to prevent razor injection is kind of a hacky solution. It's like adding icing to a burnt brownie to make it taste better. Why not just prevent it in the first place?

Instead, try this in your corresponding view:

```
<%=Html.Encode(feedback.Message)%>
```

or add

```
<text> ... </text>
```

to the inputs before they are processes.

2) If you can guarantee it's a legitimate email address, then it'll be fine. But that's hard to guarantee. So I suggest that you use a simple, yet effective email validation with JavaScript regex. This is a boolean function that you can put in your JavaScript to validate emails (this regex has a ~95% success rate):

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) 
{    
    var emailPattern = new RegExp(/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i);
    return emailPattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Comment: perhaps I didn't explain it clearly. We aren't dealing with typical user form input. This is a case where we want a client to be able to upload their own website template. It will be HTML that is decorated with template code from something like [dotliquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/). We want to be able to convert that HTML template into a razor file so it can be served as the `layout` file. We need to ensure that the html template doesn't contain any razor syntax. Simply encoding or using `<text>...` won't work in this case.
Want to update your answer?